# Rails 1.2.3 Unserializing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, checkbox

I've been assigned to fix some things in code that a previous developer created. He stored serialized checkbox values in the database and although the values are most certainly being store in the table as described, when the form comes up, the check boxes are not checked according to what was stored in the DB. I'm assuming that I need to unserialize that data before the form can know which checkboxes should be checked.

Is there a way to unserialize the exclusions data so that the following code will be able to assign a true to the checked attribute of the check_box_tag method?

```
<p><label for="supplemental_material_type_exclusions">Exclusions</label><br/>
<%= ApplicantBudgetlevel.find(:all).collect { |p|
      if @supplemental_material_type.exclusions
        checked = @supplemental_material_type.exclusions.include?(p.level)
      else
        checked = false
      end
      "#{check_box_tag('supplemental_material_type[exclusions][]', p.level, checked)} #{p.level} - #{p.range}<br />\n"
    } %>
</p>
```

Comment: The serialization he used was performed as a directive in the model. So I don't believe it's a home brewed serialization.

Comment: What kind of output do you get now?

Comment: Well, all the checkboxes appear as they should with their respect labels. The only thing that's wrong is that the serialized values of which ones were originally checked are not showing up as checked using the above posted code. I suspect it's because the values are serialized and I need them unserialized so that that if condition can determine what should be checked and what shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is a matter of *scope*; the `checked` variable only exists in one of the branches of the `if` and does not exist once the `end` is reached. Try this:

```
<p><label for="supplemental_material_type_exclusions">Exclusions</label><br/>
<%= ApplicantBudgetlevel.find(:all).collect { |p|
      checked = false
      if @supplemental_material_type.exclusions
        checked = @supplemental_material_type.exclusions.include?(p.level)
      end
      "#{check_box_tag('supplemental_material_type[exclusions][]', p.level, checked)} #{p.level} - #{p.range}<br />\n"
    } %>
</p>
```

I simply removed the `else` branch and set the value to `false` by default.

This might cause further failures if the check box should only be shown if the `if` branch is true -- in which case, try the following:

```
<p><label for="supplemental_material_type_exclusions">Exclusions</label><br/>
<%= ApplicantBudgetlevel.find(:all).collect { |p|
      if @supplemental_material_type.exclusions
        checked = @supplemental_material_type.exclusions.include?(p.level)
        "#{check_box_tag('supplemental_material_type[exclusions][]', p.level, checked)} #{p.level} - #{p.range}<br />\n"
      end
    } %>
</p>
```

Which of the two approaches is correct depends upon more than I can gauge from here -- but I'd try the first one first, and look through the logs for new or different errors or warnings.

Comment: Hi sarnold. Thank you for the excellent suggestion. Your first example will work because the checkboxes must appear all the time. I think I am now seeing the root cause. The serialized data is half of the problem. The other half is that the serialize call in the model is transposing the checkbox values of "Level 1" to "Level%25201" in the database. I am fairly confident that the if condition will never be true since a double space will never match with a single space. Can this be unencoded for the sake of the above display logic somehow?

Comment: I have a feeling that you should probably get the serialization / deserialization correct in the _model_ and try to leave the view code alone, with this fix. If you need to change the serialization code in your model to something that is more easily reversible, that sounds worth doing.

Comment: Thanks again, sarnold. I guess that's the magic question then. I'm not very good with Rails, so I am not entirely sure what my options are for this latest suggestion. I agree with you. I just am not sure how I would do this since it appears that the serialize is an ActiveRecord method but the docs don't show how to manipulate how serialization takes place and such and there's no apparent deserialization method from what I can see also. Any suggestions there?

Comment: Oh, hrm, normally you don't need to do _anything_ for the [`serialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Saving+arrays%2C+hashes%2C+and+other+non-mappable+objects+in+text+columns) directive to Just Work.

Comment: So, why is Rails using %2520 instead of %20? I can't even fathom a reason why that would make sense since it is obviously not the same thing as a single space, right?

Comment: Is there some setting somewhere that determines how serializations are encoded?

Comment: The thing is, I think it should just serialize whatever it was given as _YAML_. Are you confident the data isn't being molested on its way into the database?

Comment: From what I can tell, it appears that it's being shipped off to the model without any intervention. The model's first 3 line of code after the class declaration is "belongs_to :supplemental_material
  has_and_belongs_to_many :grants
  serialize :exclusions"

Comment: Perhaps I can transpose the values of "Level 1" into the %2520 values. Do you think that would work maybe?

Comment: I think I found the cause. It appears that there is an ajax updater called on submit of the form and as part of that definition, there's a freaking parameters:Form.serialize(this)}. Suddenly, I want to find these morons that wrote this code and cut off their hands so that they can't write stupid crap like this ever again. Thanks for all your help, sarnold.

Comment: @Skittles: hahaha, thanks for the laugh. I'm glad you found it!